# How to encapsulate OpenGL functions into C++ classes

Tags: c++, opengl, encapsulation

I want to do some scene rendering, and I want to encapsulate some OpenGL into C++ classes which I think will make the program more modularized, concise and readable. for example I want to encapsulate the framebuffer object into a C++ FBO class, pixelbuffer object into a C++ PBO class, as will as other object that may encapsulated in the class for easy of use. What I am asking is:

1. is it a good idea to encapsulate OpenGL object(FBO, PBO, VBO, VAO, etc) into C++ classes?
2. if it is, How Can I do this elegantly? any suggestion will be appreciated.
3. I think there maybe some difference to encapsulate the fixed pipeline and the programmable pipeline. as I want to learn the modern GPU programming, will can I find the material to learn how to encapsulate the modern OpenGL functions into C++ classes?

Comment: This has been done before, try doing some research in existing libraries and reading their code.

Comment: @nightcracker can you give me some more detailed information? as I want to see some lightweight methods, not a whole game engine or graphic engine which may hard to grasp.

Comment: maybe [this library](http://www.nigels.com/glt/features.html) gives you a quick start

Comment: There are two big problems related to this, explained here: http://www.opengl.org/wiki/Common_Mistakes#The_Object_Oriented_Language_Problem

Comment: @Zyx2000 thanks, I have seen the [common mistakes](http://www.opengl.org/wiki/Common_Mistakes#The_Object_Oriented_Language_Problem), but It don't give a detailed answer.

Comment: @BЈовић thanks, are there any good books to give a explain how and why to encapsulate the OpenGL functions?

Comment: They are just functions after all. Find any good oop book. In the constructor create something (like PBO) and in the destructor release. Your question is too broad.

Comment: @Zyx2000 Thanks for the great link! However, I would not advise tlh1987 against wrapping OGL functionality in a class in general. It can be very helpful, especially in larger projects. But of course you have to be careful.

Comment: You can create some useful wrappers (for FBO, textures, ...) but I think it is good to have some better purpose for doing that. Engines usually have some abstraction layer that handle graphics system (for OGL, DX, etc). If you have a small app 'raw' OpenGL syntax is enough.